# ExecuteExcel4Macro now only works when .xlms source files are open

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, extract, excel-4.0

I've been using for many years an Excel file with the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` VBA command to extract values from closed Excel files.  I've used it only on a machine with Windows 7, and it has worked flawlessly.  One caveat:  all of my closed Excel files up to this year were .xls files.

This year, the same Excel file still correctly extracts values from every closed .xls file, but it will not extract values from any closed .xlsm files. However, when I launch any of the .xlsm files (i.e., open the Excel source files), my Excel file with the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` command DOES correctly extract values from the opened .xlsm files.

Anyone know why my Excel file with the VBA code still works fine on closed .xlsm files, but generates a Type 13 error for each closed .xlms file?  I trap the error, report on it by putting a brief message in the output Excel file (the one with my VBA code), and then continue to read the next Excel file). Not a Dim error, as the macro works with all the data extracted when the source files are CLOSED.

One more piece of info: my Excel file with the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` VBA code works just fine when I run it on a Windows 10 machine. That is, it correctly extracts values from the correct cells of every one of my closed .xlsm files. So, it is only not working when: (1) I run it on my Win 7 machine, #AND# (2) the .xlms files are closed.

Comment: Obviously, the fault is with the command for opening the xls files. Without seeing the code by which the file is opened it won't be possible to determine whether it might be tweaked. Equally obvious, perhaps, is that there is a problem with compatibility. When the old xls file is opened it's converted to XML format. Since this seems to work flawlessly in WIN10 but not in WIN7 the problem might be more like a glitch in WIN7 and there might be a patch for it in one of WIN7's updates. So, try updating your WIN7 to the latest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with two possible solutions.

Comment: Thx -- I accidentally hit the Enter key.  On your first idea:  My problem is not with opening an .xls file.  My problem is reading a closed .xlsm file.  My VBA code for reading an .xlsm file only works on an .xlsm file when the .xlms source file is open.    On your second idea:  I like it.  I will update Win7 (I haven't really checked for updates lately), then see if that corrects anything.  I will comment back here to give results.

Comment: "Opening" a file is a process by which a string of bytes representing data and codes in mixed order is brought into an order by which, in the case of Excel, data are indexed to cells so that you can address them as A1 or Sheets2!C3. No data can be retrieved from any file in any app without "opening" it. Whether the data from an opened file are displayed on your screen or not is an entirely different and separate matter. Rest assured, your macro opens the file (or fails to), reads data from it (or not), and closes it (or not). BTW, you can delete your own comment or edit it within 5 minutes.

Comment: I must have written a confusing problem statement.  I am not trying to open any files.

Comment: My problem is that a VBA routine that read data from closed Excel files no long reads data from closed .xlsm files, only from closed .xls files.

Comment: What is weird with my problem is that my VBA code does read data from an .xlsm file when it is opened.  But it won't read data from the same .xlsm file when it is closed.  My VBA code WILL read data from closed .xls files, as it has for years.

Comment: Oh, thx for the tip about being able to delete my own comment within five minutes.  This is my very first post on this site, so still learning. :-)

Comment: I installed a bunch of new Windows 7 updates that have been sitting on my machine, and all went will (as usual, it took forever), even though I have a 100 Mbps connection and i7 processor.   So, thanks for getting me off my butt and installing the updates.    However, even with an up-to-date Windows 7 now installed, I still have the same problem:  my VBA code that has worked for years will not read data from any closed .xlsm file.

Comment: Yes indeed, the sun does revolve around the earth. We have been observing it for centuries even after Galileo doubted the pope's wisom. But when, one day, it doesn't rise in the east you may have to look for a reason by making different presumptions. The error seems to reside in the parameters passed to Excel when it opens the file. If the error message is to be believed, there is a wrong data type involved. So, we need to get at that command in your macro and possibly the sources of the arguments.

Comment: 1/4:  The four arguments:  path (to the closed Excel files), Excel filename, Excel worksheet name, and Excel cell.  The macro goes to that cell and reads the value in that cell, which can be a string or a value.

Comment: 2/4:  The macro still works fine (meaning no data type error) as it has for years when it is reading:  (1) a closed .xls file, (2) an open .xlsm file, or (3) on any closed or open file when running under Win 10.  So the data type is correct.

Comment: 3/4:  The macro generates Error 13 ONLY when reading a closed .xlsm file AND running on my Win 7 machine. Very narrow conditions for when it does not work.  For some reason under this narrow condition, Excel generates error 13.

Comment: 4/4:  The macro function does not generate error 13 when it is reading the same exact closed Excel file when the macro is running on Windows 10.

Comment: Let's make a deal along these lines: You show me your code and I show you where it opens the files (the part of it which isn't working). In the process we get to look for what's wrong with the code. You can modify your original question and add the code there.

Comment: How do I add my code? It exceeds the characters allowed. You say I can modify my original question.  I don't see where nor how I would do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Actual function that blows up:  HoldValue = GetValue(p, f, s, a)     [Yes, of course there is much more code, this is code that generates error.]      I used MsgBox to display the value for p, f, s, and a prior to each call to GetValue.    p=path name to folder containing the .xls and .xlsm files; f=filename of the Excel file to read; s=worksheet name inside the Excel file, and a=cell reference (e.g., $C$5).   I get a "type mismatch" error only reading the only .xlsm file in the folder.  The function correctly retrieves values from all .xls files in the same folder without any problem.

Comment: The error message says that there is a type mismatch. So we need to look at the data types of p, f, s, and a. But I suspect none of these, actually. There is a file type number needed when a file is opened. It should be an Excel enumeration (named variable), but perhaps the programmer used a hard number. Bear in mind that there were no xlsm files when the code was written. So he used the syntax valid at that time. Look for a line of code with the word `Add` or `Open` in it. To edit your question use the "edit" button at the bottom, under the tags.

Comment: If the debugger highlights `HoldValue = GetValue(p, f, s, a)` with error 13, it will be necessary to know the data type of `HoldValue` and to examine the entire function `GetVallue`, which includes checking the data types of all four arguments.

Comment: Variable type of HoldValue at that time = 10 - Error value, when it read the closed .xlsm file.   The variable type was = 8 - String, when the function read any of the closed .xls files.  I know the variable type of HoldValue because I displayed the variable type after "getting" the value from each closed file.

Comment: For background, I wrote my code to extract values from closed Excel files many years ago, based on the code presented here: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/           My code is nearly identical, and has worked for years.  And it still works flawlessly under Win 7 with closed .xls files, and works flawlessly running under Win 10 for closed .xls and .xlsm files.   It does NOT work under Win 7 to read closed .xlsm files.